# chrome extension to save link to page with highlighted text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've written a very basic chrome extension that keeps track of sentences that I've highlighted. I want to be able to link back to the sentence when I've closed the webpage where I highlighted it. i.e. I want to be able to highlight a sentence on a page, save the sentence, then close the webpage and link back to/ reopen that page and scroll the sentence into view (and possibly highlight the sentence).

The workflow goes as follows:
I have a background script, a popup and a content script.

1) I highlight the text of interest on a page.

2) I click the `save_sentence` button that I have put in the popup. A message is sent from background to the content script and the highlighted text is recorded via `window.getSelection().toString()`.

3) The highlighted sentence is sent back to the background script. The page URL is also sent back as well as other supplemental info such as the `div` that the sentence was in.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
....
        var sentence = window.getSelection().toString();
        var linker = window.location.href
        .....
        sendResponse({
            response: sentence,
            linker:linker,
            linkback:elem,
            cat:cat,
            number:number
        })
....
})
```

4) The message from content is received in the background.js and the necessary info is stored with `localStorage.setItem(...)`.

5) Then I close the page where I took the text from and now if I want to reopen that page I click a `return` button.

What I would like to happen is for the necessary info saved in `localStorage` to be used to reopen the page of origin a new tab and for the saved text to be scrolled into view. The info that has been saved in `localStorage` is as follows: `sentence` is the highlighted text, `linker` is the URL of the page where the text was taken from, `linkback` is the id/ class of the element where the text came from, `cat` is whether the identifier of the element is an `id` or `class` (to know whether to use `getElementById` or `getElementsByClassName`), `number` is the number of the element (if there is more than one element with that class/id)

background

```
$('#return').click(function() {
  var linkback=localStorage.getItem('linkback');
  var linker=localStorage.getItem('linker');
  var sentence=localStorage.getItem('sentence');
  var number=localStorage.getItem('number');
  var cat=localStorage.getItem('cat')
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: linker, active: true}); #open new tab
    var msg={
      action:'scrollto',
      linker:linker,
      linkback:linkback,
      number:number,
      cat:cat
    }
  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, msg); #send relevant info to content.js
    });
  });
```

content

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
 if(message.action==='scrollto'){
    console.log('not ready')
    chrome.tabs.update()
        console.log('ready')
        var win=message.linker
        var elem=message.elem
        var cat= message.cat
        var number=message.number
        console.log('win');
        var cat = message.cat
        if(cat === 'class'){
            destination=document.getElementsByClassName(elem)[number]
        }else{
            destination=document.getElementById(elem)[number]
        }
        var destination=$.parseHTML(message.linkback)
        console.log(destination)
        destination.scrollIntoView()
        window.scrollBy(0, -50)
}
```

## Problem

When I click the `return` button in `popup`, a new tab is opened and the popup is automatically closed and the `sendMessage` command does not seem to be executed (i.e. nothing is sent to the content script) as the text of interest is not scrolled into view.....

Overall I want to be able to highlight a sentence on a page, save the sentence, then close the webpage and link back to/ reopen that page and scroll the sentence into view (and possibly highlight the sentence).
Does anyone know of a way to do this?